# Not fetching the refresh token after validating

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I got the redirect after OAuth but then I am facing difficulty getting the refresh token from the authorization code that I got.

Hi, I'm making a simple calendar app in node.js which inserts things to the calendar using Google's API, ran into a roadblock, I managed to setup the the url redirect after OAuthm I get URL params something like this

```json
{
  code: '4/0AX4XfWgb-Jb_l5iNKI5BtHvyW8FiqX3hKgp_0GduvQsBHBRlJo4XXPykY3_Uo1HbtMixYw',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
}
```

According to what I know we need to exchange the `code` from google to get the refresh token,

Also the way I get this in my console is this

```
const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
    prompt: 'consent',
});

console.log(authUrl + 'example.com/')
```

Now how do I get the refresh token also should I save the refresh token for future use of that user? Or do I make the user login every single time

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few steps you need to exchange the authorization code now.

You should follow the [Google calendar node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/nodejs)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Calendar API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listEvents(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
}
```